# lstlisting -- javascript with react

Tags: listings

I would like to style this code line with lstlisting package.

```
let link = `https://docs.google.com/${this.props.docType}/d/${this.props.docSelected}/edit#gid=${this.props.subDocSelected}`;
```

I mean set italics for code in `` quotes but leave standard style for insert code in ${...}.

I defined own language by

```
\lstdefinelagnuage{name}{
    <sets>
}
```

It seems to me this may be related with options:

```
morecomment=[s]{`}{`},
```

or

```
morestring=[b]`
```

but I don't know how to set other style for piece of inner styled strings/comments. :)

I hope this can be done in an uncomplicated way.

thank you in advanced